# Babel Javascript Error - Multiple configuration files found

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, babeljs

### Structure

This is my project structure:

```
/app (The main code of my React app)
/assets (assets)
/core (js code)
/node_modules
/functions (Google Cloud Functions (Serverless))
   /src
   /node_modules
   /utils
   /lib
   /services
   .babelrc.js
   .eslintrc.js
   package.json

.babelrc.js
.eslintrc.js
.eslintignore
Main.js
package.json
```

### Problem

I am trying to configure babel and eslint in two folders:

1. In the root of my project
2. Inside my functions folders, which code will be deployed to Firebase.

But... I get the error:

> Parsing error: Multiple configuration files found. Please remove one: - .babelrc.js

How can I solve it?

### Configuration

This is the package.json configuration of my functions folder:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/vision": "^2.4.0",
    "@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js": "^3.3.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "camelcase": "^6.2.1",
    "expo-server-sdk": "^3.6.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.16.0",
    "glob": "^7.2.0",
    "image-size": "^0.9.7",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "qs": "^6.10.1",
    "sharp": "^0.27.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.16.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.4",
    "eslint": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.2",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.3.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

This is the .babelrc.js configuration of my functions folder:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          targets: {
            node: "current",
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

And, finally, this is the .eslintrc.js configuration of my functions folder:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "import",
    "prettier",
    "promise",
  ],
  parser: "@babel/eslint-parser",
  parserOptions: {
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "airbnb",
    "prettier",
    "google",
    "plugin:import/recommended",
  ],
  rules: ...,
  root: true,
};
```

Comment: Out of the box weboack will use the root .babelrc. you can create you own webpack build functions, but if anyone else is going to work on this, I think that would be a bad idea IMO

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, you have multiple configuration for `babel`, stated in your file(like `package.json` or `.babelrc.js`) placed in your Cloud Function. You can safely remove or delete the `.babelrc.js` inside your `/function` directory and deploy your function again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. You add into your project:

```
yarn add --save-dev eslint-plugin-import eslint-import-resolver-babel-module
```

Inside your .eslintrc file, pass this resolver to eslint-plugin-import:

```js
{
  "extends": "react-app",
  "rules": {
    "comma-dangle": 0
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "babel-module": {
        allowExistingDirectories: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```